# Comparator switching randomly

Tags: frequency, high-voltage, comparator

I cut a toroid in half, one half has unknown number of turns (50~80) which are fed to LM339 comparator which is pulled high by 500R to 3.3 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCzGfs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Purpose is to detect pulses and therefore RPM by clamping toroid to spark plug/ignition wire and closing the other half.

Any high voltage source resets my ESP32 so I first tried mains AC which should be around 50~60 Hz 220 V, comparator starts switching aggressively, turning circuit on near my bike outputs random RPM, getting close resets it.

What number of turns should I use for 220V and thousands of voltage in vehicles? Anything I can do about aggressive triggering of LM339?

I am only interested in frequency to calculate RPM. Voltage/current output from coil on toroid is barely noticeable, I tried connecting led to output of coil, LED doesn't turn on when coil is on single wire of mains AC

Comment: Can you show your measurement setup with a photo? You will not detect voltage with any such setup, only AC current.

Comment: its simply adc measuring time aka pulses whenever MCU pin is pulled low by LM339 @winny

Comment: It very much depends on the coupling factor, which can't be calculated (even the well known analytical formula implies some aproximations of uniformity & such). But you could try reading about [Rogowski coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogowski_coil).

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but your mechanical setup for sensing the magnetic field.

Comment: You can add hysteresis to the circuit to bias one input slightly high or slightly low, to stop chatter on the output when nothing's around. As it is, the inputs are connected so input/internal noise can make the output switch.

Comment: When nothing is near, output is stable high (lm339 not pulling it low), thought about adding a slight threshold for -input but signal is too weak it might stop working, no idea what hysteresis means @TonyM

Comment: Quicker for you to Google 'hysteresis' than you typing in 'no idea what hysteresis means @TonyM'.

Comment: I did google it first but could not understand how I could add or apply it @TonyM

Comment: This design is inherently unstable with pulse noise and very high open loop gain with stray oscillations of spikes from parasitic positive feedback.  The sensor L/R must be greater than the bandwidth of an integrator with a small feedback (pF) cap.

Answer (score 1):

The comparator does its job exactly as designed. It just isn't applied the way it should be. As you've set it up, the comparator gives you the *sign* of the voltage on the toroid. Now think of how that voltage looks: it's some noise and interference with spikes superimposed. If all you got is the sign, you'll get unrecognizable mess, as you've rightly noticed.

Instead, you'll want to set the threshold voltage V_T farther away from zero and rectify the signal first. Or you can use two comparators - one for +V_T, another for -V_T. Those comparators should be set up with some hysteresis, say about 10% of V_T, to reject noise better. The LM339 datasheet includes application examples for that.

There's a lot of common mode coupling from the ignition lead to your circuit. This causes the CPU resets. This is also exacerbated by construction that's not a custom PCB circuit. You'll also want to add a common mode choke where the sensor signal pair enters your PCB. Poor layout, or otherwise sloppy construction, acts as a common-mode-to-differential converter, and may even cause the MCU to be destroyed due to overvoltage. As it stands, I can almost guarantee that the MCU's ESD protection is protecting the rest of your circuit and is taking a solid beating. Not good.

Comment: can I use optocoupler at the output of comparator? will it switch fast enough, with sync with comparator?

Comment: @asim Why would you want to? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @winny coil is only placed near the sparkplug wire but MCU sharing ground with coil wire makes mcu reset and oled glitch thats why I want to separate ground from mcu with opto

Comment: Poor layout and decoupling. Fix that instead of trying to band-air it with an optocoupler.